# Java "volatile" needed for class member variables?

Tags: java, volatile

I have a question regarding the Java "volatile" keyword:

Assume, we have the following Class:

```
public class BooleanValClass {

    private boolean bolVal = false;

    public boolean getVal() {
        return this.bolVal;
    }

    public void setVal(boolean val) {
        bolVal = val;
    }
}
```

Now, assume a Thread is using this class with a "volatile" keyword:

```
private volatile BooleanValClass myClass = new BooleanValClass();
```

Do i have to attach the "volatile" keyword also to the member field "bolVal" of class "BooleanValClass" or is the "volatile" of the object reference some kind of "redirected" to all members of the class "BooleanValClass"?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: if `myClass` never changes it should be `final` rather than `volatile`. Having both, `myClass` and `bolVal`, being mutable doesn’t look sound to me.

Comment: Just as a note: there is also an `AtomicBoolean` class in Java that just can be used.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is redirected. `myClass` is volatile, `bolVal` is not. Assignments and reads from `myClass` work as volatile. Assignments/reads to/from `bolVal` don't.

Comment: correctly pointed. This only ensures that the latest changes to myClass reference (i.e. if points to some other instance) will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

In Java reading and writing fields of all types except long and double occurs atomically by JVM, and if the field is declared with the VOLATILE modifier, even long and double are become read and written atomically. Atomic garantee, that we get 100% either what was in variable, or what will calculated in variable, nor can there be any intermediate result in the variables.